# ServiceLoader not loading implementation from module

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

I have a java program that consists of 3 modules: a module containing the service as an interface, a module containing the implementation of that interface and a module containing the client that uses the implementation. The problem is, in the client module Im using `ServiceLoader` to load the Service but the `ServiceLoader` instance has no services in it. 
[image]

I tried using the keywords `provides ... with` in the `module-info.java` file in the implementation module and `uses` in the client module like this tutorial describes: https://dzone.com/articles/java-9-kickoff-project-jigsaw-and-serviceloader-part-2

**module-info.java** from service module

```
module com.em.common {
    exports com.em.common.model;
}
```

**module-info.java** from implementation module

```
module com.em.implementation {
    requires com.em.common;
    provides com.em.common.model.EmployeeService with com.em.implementation.employee.EmployeeServiceImpl;
}
```

**module-info.java** from client module

```
module com.em.client {
    requires com.em.common;
    uses com.em.common.model.EmployeeService;
}
```

**EmployeeServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.em.implementation.employee;

import com.em.common.model.Employee;
import com.em.common.model.EmployeeService;

public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    public EmployeeServiceImpl() {
        System.out.println("creating employee");
    }

    public Employee getEmployee(String firstName, String lastName) {

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setFirstName(firstName);
        employee.setLastName(lastName);
        employee.setDesignation("Unimportant Things Designer");

        return employee;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeServiceTest.java**

```
package com.em.client.employee;

import java.util.ServiceLoader;

import com.em.common.model.EmployeeService;

public class EmployeeServiceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ServiceLoader<EmployeeService> loader = ServiceLoader.load(EmployeeService.class);

        System.out.println(loader.iterator().hasNext());

    }

}
```

The `System.out.println(loader.iterator().hasNext());` prints `false` when expected is `true`. What is missing there?

Comment: When running your client module is the service-implementation module on the modulepath?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution? I'm facing the same exact issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59369028/2130408

Comment: It seems you did not "expose" the service interface via `uses` in the service module but instead in the client module, which should only declare is `requires` need on the service module. See [this blog post about Java 9 services and service providers](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/modules/services.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem as described here. The problem was that the dependency of the Provider (here: EmployeeServiceImpl.java) was missing for the Consumer (here: EmployeeServiceTest). 
Easiest solution in IntelliJ would be to add:

```java
requires Provider
```

to the Consumer. Then just:
right click -> add dependency
After that the you can remove the requires of Provider and

```java
System.out.println(loader.iterator().hasNext());
```

should print true

Comment: Is there a reason we need to specify the Provider as a dependency on the Consumer when the docs don't require it?

Answer (score -2):

Add annotation @AutoService(EmployeeService.class) in EmployeeServiceImpl class
like

@AutoService(EmployeeService.class)
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

.....

Comment: This requires [google auto-service](https://www.baeldung.com/google-autoservice) dependency and is therefore not plain java. At this point we don't know whether the OP is fine with an additional dependency or not. Further, your answer lacks a bit detail and probably requires additional research effort to be really useful