# Why won't the ServiceLoader load any implementations from another module?

Tags: java, java-module, serviceloader

I have a multi-module maven project which is making use of the JPMS features. The consumer module is not loading the implementations present in the provider module.

Here's the maven project structure:

```
ServiceLoaderExample
├── consumer
├── distribution
├── provider
├── service
```

The interface `TestService` is defined in the "service" module. The implementation is `TestServiceImpl` which is defined in the "provider" module. And the main() method in the "consumer" module uses the ServiceLoader API to load up implementations of `TestService`. And the "distribution" module is where I create a JAR with all of the dependencies using the maven-assesmbly-plugin.

As such, here are the corresponding module-info files:

1 - "service" module (which defines `org.example.service.TestService`):

```
module org.example.service {
    exports org.example.service;
}
```

2 - "provider" module (which defines `org.example.provider.TestServiceImpl`):

```
module org.example.provider {
    requires org.example.service;
    provides org.example.service.TestService with org.example.provider.TestServiceImpl;
}
```

3 - "consumer" module (which uses the ServiceLoader API to get implementations of `TestService`):

```
module org.example.consumer {
    requires org.example.service;
    uses org.example.service.TestService;
}
```

I am using the maven-assesmbly-plugin, and so it's possible things are getting screwed up when the JAR is getting built. For reference, here's the plugin definition:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>org.example.consumer.Main</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I'm using Java 13 and Maven 3.6.3, and I'm running the program using the command `java -jar distribution-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `TestServiceImpl` a `public` class with a `public` no-arg constructor?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, it is.

Comment: You can't use jar-with-dependencies("Uber-jar") and expect modules and services to work... [Modules are strictly 1 module per jar file and support is "Defer to future release"](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/issues/#MultiModuleExecutableJARs). The "normal" approach for creating a single distributable consisting of many modules is to create a [jlink image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm#JSWOR-GUID-CECAC52B-CFEE-46CB-8166-F17A8E9280E9).

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant to this question, but I found I could make ServiceLoader in module A see implementations in module B if module A depends on module B. Not exactly how I'd define "plug-in," but I am sure I'm missing some maven magic to discover and load modules somehow. (If I read your module definitions right, that isn't what you did either [packing it all in one jar would, however, solve that problem], but as I mentioned, it seems all wrong to have to do that anyway...)

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get it work with an uber-jar, however, everything does work when using JLink. So decided to just use JLink instead.